# How detailed should a Black Stories mystery be solved?

Tags: untagged

I was playing a Black Stories deck by Holger Bosch the other day when it occurred to me that the rules don't actually clarify what counts as a solved mystery. Of course, when it is not in the rules, one could argue that it doesn't matter, and the game should be played until the person holding the card and answering the questions is satisfied.

Yet, the level of detail of the solution on the back of the card makes me wonder whether the people guessing should go all the way to spell out the story or whether the details of the story are just there for the entertainment of the players who managed to crack cause of death mentioned in the story.

To give an anonymized example (none of the details are recognizable from the riddle on the front side of the card), I had a situation where:

1. A group of friends was on holiday to [destination mentioned in the story]
2. they got drunk
3. Decided to
   **a)** jump from a high place [specific high place mentioned]
   **b)** into a water body [defined in the story]
4. One member of the group did not survive [reason detailed in the story].

In this case, 4 and 3B were determined by the players, the rest was not. Does it count as solved in this way?

I know that this question is susceptible to opinion, therefore I would be interested in knowing if there has been any comment by the author of the game or by the publishers about this matter. Should it just be a decision of the cardholder to count a story as solved or is there some rule (of thumb) to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, it's up to the judgement of the one holding the card, but the [author's description](https://www.moses-verlag.de/black-stories-1/002124) is:

> Durch Raten soll genau die Geschichte dahinter herausgefunden werden.

Which translates to

*The aim is to guess the exact story behind it.*

So it seems the author intends for the detectives to work out all the parts of the story.

Now, perhaps, the you could allow that the players worked it out based on their comments amongst themselves even if they leave out this or that detail in the "official" pronouncement. So long as you can tell they know those details.